# Insert all secrets as env variables into kubernetes deployment

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-secrets

I have dozens of secrets to pass into a k8 deployment which becomes very verbose, bellow is an example of passing the redis secrets in from the `redis-secrets` secret.

```
- name: REDIS_HOST
  valueFrom:
    secretKeyRef:
      name: redis-secrets
      key: REDIS_HOST
- name: REDIS_PASSWORD
  valueFrom:
    secretKeyRef:
      name: redis-secrets
      key: REDIS_PASSWORD
- name: REDIS_PORT
  valueFrom:
    secretKeyRef:
      name: redis-secrets
      key: REDIS_PORT
```

Is it possible to pass all the secrets from `redis-secrets` into the deployment, with the keys of the secrets being the env variable key?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I used this for configmaps.

Same level as env which is `.spec.containers`:

```yaml
envFrom:
   - secretRef:
       name: redis-secrets
```

Comment: That is strange, the SecretEnvSource doesn't contain key. 
 https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.11/#secretenvsource-v1-core

Comment: Sorry - looked @ the wrong API - you are correct. Upvoted :)

Comment: The `name` attribute should be indented a level